# Print just some columns in awk

Tags: unix, awk

I was wondering how to filter just the name of the programming language from a txt file.
I have used the following sentence in AWK but I cannot get what I want:

```
($1 ~ /[A-Za-z]*/)  && ( ($3 ~ /-/) || ($4 ~ /-/) )
```

Any ideas of how to do it? Cause as you can see, there is no regular way the lines are written.

In other words, I have the following lines but I just want to print just the programming language name

```
2.PAK - AI language with coroutines.  "The 2.PAK Language: Goals and
Description", L.F. Melli, Proc IJCAI 1975.

473L Query - English-like query language for Air Force 473L system.  Sammet
1969, p.665.  "Headquarters USAF Command and Control System Query
Language", Info Sys Sci, Proc 2nd Congress, Spartan Books 1965, pp.57-76.

3-LISP - Brian Smith.  A procedurally reflective dialect of LISP which uses
an infinite tower of interpreters.
```

I just want to filter and make the following lines appear:

```
2.PAK

473L Query 

3-LISP
```

**Edit: Now would the same sentence work for the following?**

```
DML - 

  1. Data Management Language.  Early ALGOL-like language with lists,
graphics, on Honeywell 635.  

  2. "DML: A Meta-language and System for the Generation of Practical and
Efficient Compilers from Denotational Specifications"
```

I guess I just have to fix some of the RS and FS stuff so I can get this line?

```
DML
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like " - " could be a good separator, given the file:

```
$ cat /tmp/a 
2.PAK - AI language with coroutines.  "The 2.PAK Language: Goals and
Description", L.F. Melli, Proc IJCAI 1975.

473L Query - English-like query language for Air Force 473L system.  Sammet
1969, p.665.  "Headquarters USAF Command and Control System Query
Language", Info Sys Sci, Proc 2nd Congress, Spartan Books 1965, pp.57-76.

3-LISP - Brian Smith.  A procedurally reflective dialect of LISP which uses
an infinite tower of interpreters.
```

you could use the following:

```
$ awk -F ' - ' '/ - /{ print $1 }' /tmp/a
2.PAK
473L Query
3-LISP
$
```

Comment: You're welcome. Also the same command is able to parse the DML - example you added.

Comment: How would you write it as an awk file? I mean, not only in the temrinal way just as you posted

Comment: What does the instruction you posted mean @cyberz ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here it is equivalent awk script for the given command line: BEGIN{ FS=" - " } / - /{ print $1 }

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly that your file consists of multiline "stanzas" that are separated by blank lines, and each "stanza" begins with a language-name followed by  `-` , then you can write:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "\n\n"; FS = " - " } { print $1 }'
```

The `BEGIN` block (which is run before the first record is read) sets the record separator `RS` to `"\n\n"` (two newlines, i.e., a blank line), so each of your stanzas is a single AWK record, and the field separator `FS` to  `-` , so the language name is the first "field" of the stanza. The block `{ print $1 }` prints the first field in each record.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responde! @ruakh. It helped me solve the problem.

Comment: @MikePérez: You're welcome! If you could mark this as the accepted answer, I'd appreciate it. (See ["How does accepting an answer work?" on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/172535).)

Comment: Yes. But Now I have a doubt, I have modified the RS so I can filter the following lines and just get ESP:

ESP -

  1. Extra Simple Pascal.  Subset of Pascal.

  2. Econometric Software Package.  Statistical analysis of time series. 

What I wrote in the awk program is BEGIN { RS = "\n\n\n\n\n"; FS = " - " } 
But I cannot make it work, any idea why?

Comment: @MikePérez: Since line-breaks don't show up in comments, I'm not sure I exactly understood . . . but `RS = "\n\n\n\n\n"` means that you expect records to be separated by sequences of five newlines, that is, sequences of four blank lines. I don't think that can be what you want?

Comment: Oh I got it. Nope, I do not want that ... What I want is to filter something like the parragraph I edited here in my post

Comment: @MikePérez: Ah, O.K., then your input doesn't satisfy the assumption that stanzas are separated by blank lines: you can have a blank line inside a stanza. An approach like cyberz's might work better for you, then, or you might combine the approaches.