# Parse columns with awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I am new at AWK programming and I was wondering how to filter the following text:

```
Goedel - Declarative language for AI, based on many-sorted logic.  Strongly
typed, polymorphic, declarative, with a module system.  Supports bignums
and sets.  "The Goedel Programming Language", P. M. Hill et al, MIT Press
1994, ISBN 0-262-08229-2.  Goedel 1.4 - partial implementation in SICStus
Prolog 2.1.
ftp://ftp.cs.bris.ac.uk/goedel
info: goedel@compsci.bristol.ac.uk
```

Just to print this:

```
Goedel
```

I have used the following sentence but it just does not work as I wished:

```
awk -F " - " "/ - /{ print $1 }"
```

It shows the following:

```
Goedel
1994, ISBN 0-262-08229-2.  Goedel 1.4
```

Could somebody tell me what I have to modify so I can get what I want?

Thanks in advance

Comment: (Relevant background: ["Print just some columns in awk" on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175797/print-just-some-columns-in-awk).)

Comment: Given what you've told us so far we could write a script that just does `awk 'BEGIN{print "Goedel"}'` and it'd satisfy your requirements. Tells us more and possibly supply more input/output. Do you just want the first word of the file, the first word before a `-`, the first word that starts with a capital letter, the second word from a quoted string, the first word that appears twice, the last word from the ftp line capitalized, the leading part of an email address capitalized, or something else?

Comment: Your script prints anything before " - " just like you specified. If your specification doesn't match what you actually want, work on the specification, not the software.

Comment: Another related question by the same user: [How to filter columns in `awk`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177031/how-to-filter-columns-in-awk)  In fact, this question is basically asking the same thing as the previous one.

Comment: Since your sample input data doesn't include Goedel, how does it appear in the output?

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{print "Goedel"}{print $1;exit}' file.txt` would produce your stated output, but given the lack of clarity of your question, I suspect it's probably not the solution you're looking for.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, because you were basically changing it to a new question. Please don't do that - accept one of the answers here (or delete this question if it won't help anyone) and post a new question instead, ideally with a close eye on the [site's guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } { print $1 }' your_file.txt`

which means: [splits string into paragraphs by empty line](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html), and then splits words by the default separator (space), and finally print the first word ($1) of every paragraph

Comment: Thanks @Alec but I have many parragraphs just as that one in the same txt file, how would that line parse just the first word of each parragraph of the file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MikePérez modified to meet your needs

Comment: Thanks @Alec, although I cannot filter as I wished. It helped parse the parragraphs similar to that but not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

this one-liner could work for your requirement:

```
awk -F ' - ' 'NF>1{print $1;exit}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F ' - ' ' { if (FNR % 4 == 1) next; print $1; }'
```

If the format is exactly the same as below, then the code above should work:

```
1 Author - ...
2 Year ...
3 URL
4 Extra info ...
5 Author - ...
6..N etc.
```

If there is a blank line between entries, you can set `RS` to a null string and `$1` will be the author as long as the value for -F (the FS variable in an awk script) is the same. This has the advantage that if you don't have "info: ..." or a URL, you can still distinguish between entries, assuming it is not "Author - ...{newline}Year ...{newline}{newline}info: ...{newline}{newline}Author - ..." (you can't have an empty line between parts of an entry if an empty line is what separates entries.) For example:

```
# A blank line is what separates each entry.
BEGIN { RS = ""; }

{ print $1; }
```

If you have an awk that supports it, you can make RS a multiple character string if necessary (e.g. `RS = "\n--\n"` for entries separated by "--" on a line by itself). If you need a regex or simply don't have an awk that supports multiple character record separators, you're forced to use something like the following:

```
BEGIN { found_sep = 1; }

{ if (found_sep) { print $1; found_sep = 0; } }

# Entry separator is "--\n"
/^--$/ { found_sep = 1; }
```

More sample input will be required for something more complicated.